# What is the difference b/w AuthFlow ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH and ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH in Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Our login flow: client->server->cognito

We are using **InitiateAuth() API** with **USER_PASSWORD_AUTH** AuthFlow. We are go to enable Advanced security in Cognito, for which we are going to use **AdminInitiateAuth()** API with Ip address and finger print data.

Can you suggest me which AuthFlow is good for my scenario (We are passing USERNAME, PASSWORD and SECRET_HASH as a AuthParameters).

Can you also tell me the main difference b/w **ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH** and **ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH** AuthFlow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which auth flow is good for my scenario?

The `AdminInitiateAuth` API with ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH is good since you're doing server-to-server auth.

> Difference between ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH & ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH auth flows?

ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH was formerly known as ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH.

---

> If you have a server-side app:
>
> 1. It calls the `AdminInitiateAuth` API. This requires AWS admin credentials & returns the authentication parameters.
> 2. It then calls the `AdminRespondToAuthChallenge` API, which also requires AWS admin credentials.
>
> The `AdminInitiateAuth` and `AdminRespondToAuthChallenge` operations can't accept username & password user credentials for admin sign-in, unless you explicitly enable them to do so by doing one of the following:
>
> - Pass **ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH (formerly known as ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH)** for the `ExplicitAuthFlow` parameter in your server-side app's call to `CreateUserPoolClient` or `UpdateUserPoolClient`.
> - Choose **Enable sign-in API for server-based authentication (ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH)** in the **App clients** tab in **Create a user pool**.

— [Server-Side Auth Flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-server-side-authentication-flow) — Cognito Documentation

> Example:
>
> ```
> AdminInitiateAuth Request {
>     "AuthFlow": "ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
>     "AuthParameters": {
>         "USERNAME": "<username>",
>         "PASSWORD": "<password>"
>     },
>     "ClientId": "<clientId>",
>     "UserPoolId": "<userPoolId>"
> }
> ```

— [Admin Auth Flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-admin-authentication-flow) — Cognito Documentation

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. `ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` was formerly known as `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH`. For details about the authentication flow have a look at [User Pool Authentication Flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html).